# missing artifact org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:5.0.0-alpha1

Tags: maven, elasticsearch

Even though I can see the JAR file in Maven Dependencies and in .m2/repository directory, I still get this error.

[missing artifact org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXXY7.png)

Do you have any idea where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same question.You can try the flowing steps:

1.make sure your network is well connected.

2.go to .m2/repository,delete all the files

3.restart your project and run maven install and maven update.

Answer (score 0):

After running a build from the shell (`mvn clean install`, etc.) and making sure the problem is caused by Eclipse - there are a few options:

- First, try *Project* --> *Clean...*
- Right click on the project in the Project Explorer pane and then choose *Maven* --> *Update Project...*
- Disable and then re-enable *Dependency Management* - right click *Maven* --> *Disable Dependency Management* and then *Maven->Enable Dependency Management*
- Close the project and then reopen it.